# Is there a way to ensure that PBS array jobs will be run in order?

Tags: hpc, pbs

I run many PBS scripts that take advantage of the job array structure for similar jobs (e.g. 12345[0] through 12345[9]). With the way that the code is written, job [0] needs to run first, and then any other job can start. Preferably, the jobs would run in numerically increasing order.

When I submit an array of jobs, they all have the same priority and queue time, but are listed in a random order. I don't have the permissions to change the priority once a job is submitted (AFAIK), so I am looking for a solution during the job submission.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a guarantee, submit element zero as a separate job and make 1-9 dependent on its completion.